# Unable to FTP data from GSM module

Tags: gsm, at-command, ftp-client

I am a newbie, I am using Quectel ec25-e GSm module. I am trying to send upload & and download data from FTP server. For this I am have gone through following steps:-

```
 1. AT+QICSGP=1,1,"WWW","","",1 //Configure PDP context 1
 2. AT+QIACT=1 //Activate PDP context 1.
 3. AT+QFTPCFG="contextid",1 //Configure the PDP context ID as 1
 4. AT+QFTPCFG="account","User","pass" //Set user name and password
 5. AT+QFTPCFG="filetype",1 //Set file type as binary
 6. AT+QFTPCFG="transmode",1 //Set transfer mode as passive mode.
 7. AT+QFTPCFG="rsptimeout",150 //Set response timeout value
 8. AT+QFTPOPEN="122.160.158.240",21    // Login to FTP server
```

Login part is working fine, Now I choose my working directory :-

```
AT+QFTPCWD="/test" //Set current directory.
```

I can also create, rename and delete folder with following commands:-

```
AT+QFTPMKDIR="check" //Create a folder as “check” on FTP(S) server.
AT+QFTPRENAME="check","check1"   //Rename a folder.
AT+QFTPRMDIR="check1"  //Delete a folder
```

Till now every thing is fine. but now i am trying to list out all file is the folder ( while I know I have some file out there), it just wait for timeout and then give error. My command is :-

```
AT+QFTPNLST="." //List file names of current directory
```

And my output is:-

```
+CME ERROR: 609
```

+CME ERROR: 609 means Timeout error .And same goes with uploading data.unfortunately Quectel is not providing documents for this module anymore. So, I can't share link. So I am attaching screen shots of application notes.Please tell me what i am missing here[image][image][image][image]

Note* i have upgraded GSM firmware, but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in FTP trans mode should be in active mode, so changing

```
AT+QFTPCFG="transmode",1
```

to

```
AT+QFTPCFG="transmode",0
```

works.